# relaying party name in claim rule

Tags: adfs2.0

I would like to use the name of the relying party in my Claim Rules. Does anyone know if and how I can get that?

(use case is: send out this data for ClaimX if the RP-Name is 'xxx', send out that data for ClaimX if the RP-Name is 'yyy')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused by this.

I assume you are talking about claims rules for a Claims Provider?

Each Relying Party has its own set of claims rules so RP xxx has its rules which can be completely different to the claims rules for RP yyy.

For the CP, there is a one-to-one relationship between a CP and its associated RP. So every CP "knows" which RP they are connected to.

Each CP has its own set of claims rules for its associated RP so the CP for RP xxx can have rules which can be completely different to the claims rules for the CP associated with RP yyy.

What scenario are you talking about? Can you expand on this please?

Comment: yeah, it's clear now that every RP can have its own rules. Thanks.